# How to read pixel data of image in an ushort array and export this ushort array as a binary file in c#

Tags: c#

i have one Tiff image it is an 16 bit image, now i want to read the pixel data as ushort array and stored it to binary format in text file.

i have sample code.

```
// Load file meta data with FileInfo
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path + "output.tif");

            // The byte[] to save the data in
            byte[] data = new byte[fileInfo.Length];
            // Load a filestream and put its content into the byte[]
            using (FileStream fs = fileInfo.OpenRead())
            {
                fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

          ushort[] result = Array.ConvertAll(data, b => (ushort)b);
```

but it is reading meta data, i want to read pixel data.

Comment: `TiffBitmapEncoder` could be helpfull: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-encode-and-decode-a-tiff-image

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use an external library for handling tiff files. It is a complex file format which can contain more than one image, the image(s) can be compressed etc. So just reading the byte array is definitely not helping you getting the pixel values. And even if it just contained the color values of the pixels, you still had to combine every two bytes for a 16 bit image.

In your sample code, you just convert bytes to ushorts, meaning that you precede the numbers with zeroes, which does not change the value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, an Image is already a binary.

Here, I don't understand the purpose of explicitly converting an image to `ushort` array. Apart from that, You can simply save all bytes of Tiff image to a text file like this:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"Text file path", File.ReadAllBytes(@"Tiff image file path"));
```

Then to read it back from the binary file you can simply read all bytes from the saved text file and using `MemoryStream` and save it back to image.

```
using (Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(@"Text file path"))))
{
    image.Save(@"Path to save image", ImageFormat.Tiff);
}
```